# How should I go about translating my company name in Japanese?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate a company name ("puddle") in to Japanese. I put it into Google Translate, but when you translate words, you're translating their meaning rather than the word itself, which is usually what you're looking for. But when translating a company name, essentially you want to find the letter for letter equivalent of that name.

What's the best way to approach this?

Also, how can you check that you haven't accidentally translated your company name into an obscenity?

Comment: Welcome! Japanese Language and Usage - Stack Exchange is for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language. Questions like this aren't a great fit for the site because they're too localised (i.e. unlikely to be useful to anyone else), and are so basic that they can be looked up in a dictionary. Therefore, this question is likely to be closed. However, questions like this are fine on chat (once you gain enough rep to participate there), and you're certainly welcome to ask other questions, but it might be a good idea to check the FAQ first.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple doesn't translate itself as ringo in Japanese, so I don't think translating puddle would make sense.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Which makes me wonder: could a radical rephrase save this question? Something like "How should I go about translating my company name in Japanese?"

Comment: @ジョン: If the asker edits the question as you suggested, I will vote to reopen.  I do not think that other people should edit a question drastically (rather they should ask a new question separately, perhaps with a link to the original question, if they want to know about the new question) because that would put the responsibility of choosing the best answer for the new question on the original asker, who may not be interested in the new question.

Comment: What is the point of just editing the title without changing anything in the actual question?  I am afraid that you are missing the point of ジョン’s comment.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I agree, edits like this really need to be done by the asker. Sam: If you want to improve the question you need to edit the main body also. We don't do personalised translations here, but a more general question on how company names should be translated could actually be a very interesting question.

Comment: sure ill change it now

Comment: That looks better, thanks for persevering :) I will vote to re-open. (and mention @TsuyoshiIto in case he'd like to take another look)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the best way to approach this?

Ask someone who is fluent in Japanese to help you out. Another problem people run into is when the name they want to use is already in use. A good example is the company Logitech (the computer accessory maker). In Japan they are known as Logicool because [another company](http://www.logitec.co.jp/) that was already in Japan had a similar name.

> Also how can you check that you haven't accidentally translated your company name into an obscenity?

Same as above, to verify your name is okay, you need to ask someone who understands Japanese well. Another common problem is when you use Katakana, it can mean different things, for example, パドル could also be translated back into English as "paddle", so it might be best to leave the title in English, or think of a different name.